# Using multiprocessing to process image but no performance gain with 8 cpus

Tags: python, numpy

I got a function called `cartoonize(image_path)`, which takes 'path/to/image' as an argument. The script is a bit hefty takes a couple of minutes to process a 1920x1080 sized image. I tried to use all my `8 cores` using `multiprocessing module`, but there is no performance gain I see with the following code. Another problem is how to save the image. It returns a CV2 object. Normally, I save the image to the disk by `see below code`, but with multiprocessing it is giving error `"img is not a numpy array, neither a scalar."` I also want a performance gain, which I can't figure out how to do it efficiently.

```
out_final = cartoonize('path/to/image'))
cv2.imwrite('cartoon.png', out_final)



import multiprocessing

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # mark the start time
    startTime = time.time()

    print "cartoonizing please wait ..."
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    pool_outputs = pool.apply_async(cartoonize, args=(image_path,))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print ('Pool:', pool_outputs)

    # mark the end time
    endTime = time.time()
    print('Took %.3f seconds' % (startTime - endTime))
```

Comment: Multiprocessing will not automatically just boost performance like magic. You need to feed it units of work.  If you only give it one image to process what can it parallelize? Note: Some image processing libs ARE capable of breaking up a single image into many units of work...but that is likely not the case here.

Comment: @RalphCaraveo, its a good. I would like to split into many parts and process them individually I thought before that. Can you give me suggestion how to save an image, here? basically its an CV object but I am receiving an multiprocessing object here.

Comment: You should actually lose performance with that script. As you are actually applying the same function to the same whole image for each core you have.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: multiprocessing it is giving error "img is not a numpy array, neither a scalar."

```
pool_outputs = pool.apply_async(cartoonize, args=(image_path,))
```

Your code returns `AsyncResult`

> **Python » 3.6.1 Documentation** » [multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult)
>   class multiprocessing.pool.AsyncResult
>   The class of the **result returned by Pool.apply_async()** and Pool.map_async().